# C++ : integer constant is too large for its type

Tags: c++, gcc

I need to bruteforce a year for an exercise. The compiler keep throwing this error:

> bruteforceJS12.cpp:8:28: warning: integer constant is too large for its type [enabled by default]

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    unsigned long long year(0);
    unsigned long long result(318338237039211050000);
    unsigned long long pass(1337);

    while (pass != result)
    {
    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i<= year; i++)
        {

        pass += year * i * year;

        }

        cout << "pass not cracked with year = " << year << endl;
        ++year;

    }

        cout << "pass cracked with year = " << year << endl;
}
```

Note that I already tried with `unsigned long long result(318338237039211050000ULL);`

I'm using gcc version 4.8.1

EDIT:

Here is the corrected version using InfInt library http://code.google.com/p/infint/

```
#include <iostream>
#include "InfInt.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    InfInt year = "113";
    InfInt result = "318338237039211050000";
    InfInt pass= "1337";

    while (pass != result)
    {
    for (InfInt i = 1; i<= year; i++)
        {

        pass += year * i * year;

        }

        cout << "year = " << year << "  pass = " << pass <<  endl;
        ++year;

    }

        cout << "pass cracked with year = " << year << endl;
}
```

Comment: you should use ASCII representation.

Comment: Does it fail with `unsigned long long result = 318338237039211050000ULL;`?  Is it possibly just that it doesn't like that initialization method?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein: Literal suffixes are not for *that* purpose. An integer literal already has a type that can represent it if such a type exists.

Comment: ` warning: integer constant is too large for its type` ... It can't be stored in a unsigned long long variable. It's all.

Comment: Use `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()` to see what your problem is. 318338237039211050000 is clearly greater than 18446744073709551615.

Comment: `int128_t` should be big enough, if you have access to that type. [69 bits required](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=318338237039211050000&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=log%28318338237039211050000%29+%2F+log%282%29&safe=off)

Comment: Too many of these *comments* look like *answers* - why not post an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way to figure out the numeric limits on your system would be to use [std::numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). The output on my system when I run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{   
     std::cout << "ull\t"
              << std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::lowest() << '\t'
              << std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() << std::endl ;
}
```

is:

```
ull 0   18446744073709551615
```

we can see the max value is definitely smaller than your literal value:

```
 18446744073709551615
 318338237039211050000
```

So your integer literal is just too large for *unsigned long long* type.

Comment: Thank you. Instead of trying to find a library that support this operation, I will implement the same code with python.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simply that `318338237039211050000ULL` is out of range.

Assuming a 64 bit type, a 64 bit value is good for log10( 2<sup>64</sup>-1) decimal digits (i.e. all 19 digit values and some lower 20 digit values), `318338237039211050000ull` has 21 digits.  2<sup>64</sup>-1 (`18446744073709551615ull`) is the maximum.

The value 318338237039211050000 requires at least log10(318338237039211050000)/log10(2) bits.  That's 69 bits.

Comment: You don't need the suffix; the compiler gives it a type that will hold the value.

Comment: @petebecker all integer literals are defaulted to int, so you need to use suffix

Comment: @texasbruce: That's incorrect. The type of an unsuffixed decimal integer literal is the first of `int`, `long int`, `long long int` that can represent its value. (That list was different in earlier versions of the standard.) See section 2.14.2 [lex.icon] in the C++ standard.

Comment: @KeithThompson: We live and learn. Since it is not relevant to the answer, I've removed the comment about the suffix. I'd swear I've had compilers report errors for exceeding the size of an int. Maybe in C90 rather than C++ and certainly before C++98 - I've been doing this a long time. Applying the suffix is now a habit of mine, and probably not a bad habit.  The default type of the literal value may not match the type to which it is assigned, so for strict type agreement it remains perhaps "good practice" rather than a requirement.

Comment: @Clifford: The C90 rule was that an unsuffixed decimal literal is of type `int`, `long int`, or `unsigned long int`. In C++98 it was `int` or `long int`. Pre-standard compilers could have required `int`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Thanks.  And of course `long long` was not a standard type in either C or C++ until later standards.  I am an embedded systems developer and unless using GCC, C++11 and to some extent even C99 compilers are not necessarily a given. In some cases these more niche architecture specific compilers generate tighter code than GCC so continue to be used.  So I'll stick with the habit because portability between compilers at different compliance levels is important in my area of work.  The question specified GCC 4.8.1, it is clear that the ULL suffix is as you say not *required*.